# How to return first place and ties?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Goal: Which 'reptile' specie has the most exams? Display the animal_id and an_name. Possible ties for 1st - in that case all tied animals should be returned.

Reptile: chelonian, crocodilian, lizard, snake

How do I go about filtering out the specie that has the most exam and include ties?

My Code so far...

```
SELECT AN.an_id, AN.an_name, COUNT(EH.ex_date)
FROM vt_animals AS AN
INNER JOIN vt_exam_headers AS EH ON EH.an_id = AN.an_id
WHERE AN.an_type IN ('snake', 'chelonian', 'crocodilian', 'lizard')
GROUP BY AN.an_id, AN.an_name
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES AN.an_id, AN.an_name, COUNT(EH.ex_date) as cnt
FROM vt_animals AS AN
INNER JOIN vt_exam_headers AS EH ON EH.an_id = AN.an_id
WHERE AN.an_type IN ('snake', 'chelonian', 'crocodilian', 'lizard')
GROUP BY AN.an_id, AN.an_name
ORDER BY COUNT(EH.ex_date) DESC
```